# Angular variable not updating

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create an angular app to drop markers on a map. When you click the map, a function generates the marker and opens a form and then another function logs the position. You enter a description into the form and then when you submit it, the form updates a json database. The problem I'm having is that I can't get the position information to update.

HTML:

```
  <div class="jumbotron" id="map container" style="position: relative">
    <h1>Map in Angular</h1>

    <!--Map image-->
    <div (click)="logCursorPosition(e)" (click)="getCursorPositionX(e)" (click)="getCursorPositionY(e)" ></div>
    <img id="map" src="../assets/img/summonersRift.jpg" width="960" height="540" >
  </div>

<!--form appears on marker placement-->
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
  <form class="form-container" #mapMarker="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="markerFormSubmit(mapMarker.value)">
    <input type="text"   class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Description" name="description" ngModel>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel btn-sm" (click)="closeForm()">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn delete btn-sm">Delete</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import { DndDatabaseService } from './dnd-database.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { markerData } from './markerData';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'map-app';

  constructor(private dndDatabaseService: DndDatabaseService,
              private httpClient: HttpClient,
              private http: HttpClient){};

  iconDescription:Object={};
  xPosition:Object={};
  yPosition:Object={};







  ngOnInit(){
      const iconImage = new Image();
      iconImage.src = "../assets/img/marker.jpg"

      //subscribes to the JSON file
      this.httpClient.get<markerData[]>('http://localhost:3000/mapMarker')
      .subscribe(posts => {
          posts.forEach(post=>{
                setMarker(post)})})      

      //Generate the markers from the json data
      function setMarker(post){
        console.log("function started", post.id)
        var x = post.xPos;
        var y = post.yPos;
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "../assets/img/marker.jpg";
        img.width = 20;
        img.height= 20;
        img.style.position="absolute";
        img.style.left= (x-20)+'px';
        img.style.top=(y-40)+'px';
        document.getElementById('map container').appendChild(img);
      }

      //Listen for map events
      var map = document.getElementById('map')
      map.addEventListener("click", this.logCursorPosition);
      map.addEventListener("click", this.getCursorPositionX);
      map.addEventListener("click", this.getCursorPositionY);



  }

  getCursorPositionX(e){
    var x = (e.clientX)-20;
    //console.log("x:", x)
    this.xPosition = {"x": x};
    return this.xPosition
  }

  getCursorPositionY(e){
    var y = (e.clientY)-40;
    //console.log("y:", y)
    this.yPosition = {"y": y};
    return this.yPosition
  }

  logCursorPosition(e){
      //Get Cursor Location
      var x = e.clientX;
      var y = e.clientY;
      console.log("X Position "+ x + " Y Position" +y);
      //Place Icon
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = "../assets/img/marker.jpg";
      img.width = 20;
      img.height= 20;
      img.style.position="absolute";
      img.style.left= (x-20)+'px';
      img.style.top=(y-40)+'px';
      document.getElementById('map container').appendChild(img);
      img.id="currentMarker"
      //Open Form
      document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block"; //Opens the form
      document.getElementById('myForm').style.top = y +'px'; // sets the form y coordinate
      document.getElementById('myForm').style.left = x +'px'; // sets the form x coordinate
  }

//function that opens and closes the form for the icons
closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}


  markerFormSubmit(marker){
      this.iconDescription ={
        "description": marker.description,
        "xPos":this.xPosition,
        "yPos":this.yPosition,
      }
    this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/mapMarker", this.iconDescription).subscribe((po:Response) => {console.log("po",po)})
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
    alert("Successfully Added")
  }
}
```

Db File

```
{
  ],
  "mapMarker": [
    {
      "description": "Example",
      "xPos": 450,
      "yPos": 450,
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "description": "middle",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you be slightly more specific as to where I should do this? In the getCursorPosition functions for the this.Position value?

Comment: I don't think using arrow function will solve your issue, sorry about that, If it possible can you create stackblitz?

Comment: I updated the stackblitz so now it actually works, except for the marker images
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z8nxkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save items in localStorage. For example, you can set xPosition to x here:

```
getCursorPositionX(e){
    var x = (e.clientX)-20;
    localStorage.setItem("xPosition", x)
}
```

Then you can call it again when you need it here:

```
markerFormSubmit(marker){
  this.iconDescription ={
    "description": marker.description,
    "xPos": localStorage.getItem("xPosition"),
    "yPos": localStorage.getItem("yPosition"),
  }
this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/mapMarker", 
this.iconDescription).subscribe((po:Response) => 
    {console.log("po",po)})
document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
alert("Successfully Added")
```

}

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not the solution I went with, however I recently learned about localStorage for another part of my app and this would work so I'm marking it as correct. Thank you for the help.